How to resize textarea by dragging in React Testing Library?
I need to test if Material UI's TextareaAutosize remains smooth while resizing. Since it uses an HTML textarea, I want to simulate resizing it with the mouse, using the grabber on the bottom-right corner.
I'm attempting to test the resizing behavior of TextareaAutosize component in the following way:
it('should not glitch when resizing textarea', function test() {
  if (/jsdom/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
    this.skip();
  }

  const { container } = render(<TextareaAutosize />);
  const textarea = container.querySelector<HTMLTextAreaElement>('textarea')!;

  console.log('before textarea.style.height: ', textarea.style.height);

  // Get the element's dimensions
  const { top, left, width, height } = textarea.getBoundingClientRect();

  // Calculate coordinates of bottom-right corner
  const bottomRightX = left + width;
  const bottomRightY = top + height;

  fireEvent.mouseDown(textarea, { clientX: bottomRightX, clientY: bottomRightY });
  fireEvent.mouseMove(textarea, { clientX: bottomRightX + 50, clientY: bottomRightY + 50 });
  fireEvent.mouseUp(textarea);

  console.log('after textarea.style.height: ', textarea.style.height);
});

I've set it up to run the test in the browser, not on JSDOM, with this check:
  if (/jsdom/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
    this.skip();
  }

However, I'm encountering an issue where the value of textarea.style.height remains the same before and after the mouse event, even though I expect it to change.
Chrome Headless 123.0.6312.4 (Windows 10) LOG: 'before textarea.style.height: ', '15px'
Chrome Headless 123.0.6312.4 (Windows 10) LOG: 'after textarea.style.height: ', '15px'

The height of the textarea should increase after the mouse interaction, but it seems like it's not actually resizing. I'm unsure if the dragging action is being properly simulated.

It seems like the dragging action to simulate resizing the textarea might not be properly simulated. Check if the fireEvent.mouseMove event is accurately updating the textarea's height. You might need to adjust the coordinates or try a different approach to simulate the resizing.

@Djamanmotihari How can I verify that the fireEvent.mouseMove event is correctly updating the textarea's height? The height remains unchanged in the after log. Do you have any suggestions for alternative approaches I could try?

AFAIK the ability to interact with a resize handle in the corner of a textarea is a native UI affordance of the browser (similar to the resize interaction offered at the edge of a window). While these handles can be disabled via CSS, I don't think they are available to any browser JavaScipt APIs, so RTL might not be the right tool for such a test. Puppeteer's mouse API might be able to simulate the behavior you have in mind.

@jsejcksn Thanks for the answer. We use Playwright for e2e testing, and I was able to add a test for it with Playwright.

I resolved it using E2E testing with Playwright, instead of using React testing libraries. Below is the test implementation:
First, the component rendered for testing:
import * as React from 'react';
import { TextareaAutosize } from '@mui/base/TextareaAutosize';

function BasicTextareaAutosize() {
  return <TextareaAutosize data-testid="textarea" />;
}

export default BasicTextareaAutosize;

Here's the e2e test:
it('should not glitch when resizing', async () => {
  await renderFixture('TextareaAutosize/BasicTextareaAutosize');

  const textarea = await screen.getByTestId('textarea')!;

  // Get the element's dimensions
  const { x, y, width, height } = (await textarea.boundingBox())!;

  // Calculate coordinates of bottom-right corner
  const bottomRightX = x + width;
  const bottomRightY = y + height;

  // Get the initial height of textarea as a number
  const initialHeight = await textarea.evaluate((event) => parseFloat(event.style.height));

  // Move the mouse to the bottom-right corner, adjusting slightly to grab the resize handle
  await page.mouse.move(bottomRightX - 5, bottomRightY - 5);

  // Simulate a double click without releasing the mouse button (mouseup) to grab the resize handle
  await page.mouse.down();
  await page.mouse.up();
  await page.mouse.down();

  // Move the mouse to resize the textarea
  await page.mouse.move(bottomRightX + 50, bottomRightY + 50);

  // Assert that the textarea height has increased after resizing
  expect(await textarea.evaluate((event) => parseFloat(event.style.height))).to.be.greaterThan(
    initialHeight,
  );
});

